# Insert values into XML column child node Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table1

```
Deptno  Skills

1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       3
3       1
3       2
```

I need to insert the skills value as a child node to an XMl column in table2 with respect to matching Deptno

**Tried using**

```
UPDATE 
   Dept
SET 
   XMLColumn.modify('insert ('Skills 2 /Skills)
   as last into
   (/Skills[1])
   ') where deptno = 1
```

But how can I use other table values and nest them into table2 xml column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
update T2
set XMLColumn.modify('insert sql:column("T1.Skills") as last into Skills[1]')
from Table2 as T2
  cross apply (
              select T1.Skills
              from Table1 as T1
              where T2.Deptno = T1.Deptno
              for xml path(''), type
              ) as T1(Skills)
where T2.Deptno = 1
```

Build the XML you want to insert in a cross apply correlated on `Deptno` and use `sql:column()` to pull the generated XML into your `modify()` statement.